# Transaction order in MulticallV2 contract

Tags: ethers.js

I'm trying to initialize a pool and mint a position in UniswapV3 with this code:

```
export const createInitializeMintToken = async (
  token0: string,
  token1: string,
  fee: number,
  sqrtPriceX96: string,
  tickLower: number,
  tickUpper: number,
  amount0Desired: string,
  amount1Desired: string,
  amount0Min: string,
  amount1Min: string,
  recipient: string,
  deadline: string
) => {
  try {

    const signer = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum).getSigner(
      recipient
    )

    const nonfungible = new ethers.Contract(
      nftAddress,
      Nonfungiblepositionmanager.abi,
      signer
    )

    const positionManager = new ethers.Contract(
      nftAddress,
      Nonfungiblepositionmanager.abi,
      signer
    )

    if (token0 >= token1) {
      ;[token0, token1] = [token1, token0]
      sqrtPriceX96 = String(
        priceToSqrtPrice(1 / sqrtPriceToPrice(Number(sqrtPriceX96)))
      )
    }

    
    const mintingParams = {
      token0: token0,
      token1: token1,
      fee: fee,
      tickLower: tickLower,
      tickUpper: tickUpper,
      amount0Desired: amount0Desired,
      amount1Desired: amount1Desired,
      amount0Min: amount0Min,
      amount1Min: amount1Min,
      recipient: recipient,
      deadline: deadline,
    }

    const calls = [
      positionManager.createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary(
        token0,
        token1,
        fee,
        String(BigInt(Number(sqrtPriceX96))),
        {
          value: "0", 
        }
      ),
      nonfungible.mint(mintingParams, {
        value: "0"
      })
    ]

  const multicall = new ethers.Contract(mullticallAddress, UniswapInterfaceMulticall.abi, signer)
  multicall.aggregate(calls)      
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error, "error for CreateInitializeMintToken")
  }
}
```

No matter which is the index of mint function, it's aways called first. The function that i'm calling is this one from Multicall2:

```
function aggregate(Call[] memory calls) public returns (uint256 blockNumber, bytes[] memory returnData)
```

Can someone give me a hint over this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who wanna know how this ends:

```
export const createInitializeMintToken = async (
  token0: string,
  token1: string,
  token0Decimals: number,
  token1Decimals: number,
  fee: number,
  price: number,
  tickLower: number,
  tickUpper: number,
  amount0Desired: bigint,
  amount1Desired: bigint,
  amount0Min: bigint,
  amount1Min: bigint,
  recipient: string,
  deadline: number,
  chainId: number
) => {
  try {
    const wrappedToken0 = ifNativeUseWrapped(token0, chainId).tokenAddress
    const wrappedToken1 = ifNativeUseWrapped(token1, chainId).tokenAddress

    // createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary() internally requires that "token0 < token1", so if that's false we need to invert every value
    if (wrappedToken0.toLowerCase() > wrappedToken1.toLowerCase()) {
      // first, we flip all TOKEN0/TOKEN1 parameters into TOKEN1/TOKEN0 parameters
      ;[token0, token1] = [token1, token0]
      ;[tickLower, tickUpper] = [tickUpper, tickLower]
      ;[amount0Desired, amount1Desired] = [amount1Desired, amount0Desired]
      ;[amount0Min, amount1Min] = [amount1Min, amount0Min]
      // next, we invert the relevant values
      price = 1 / price
      tickLower = -tickLower
      tickUpper = -tickUpper
    }
    const sqrtPrice = priceToSqrtPrice(price, token0Decimals, token1Decimals)

    const txData = getNativeValueAndWrappedAddresses(
      chainId,
      token0,
      token1,
      amount0Desired,
      amount1Desired
    )
    token0 = txData.token0Address
    token1 = txData.token1Address
    const nativeCurrencyValue = txData.nativeCurrencyValue
    const isToken0Native = txData.isToken0Native
    const isToken1Native = txData.isToken1Native

    const mintingParams = {
      token0: token0,
      token1: token1,
      fee: fee,
      tickLower: tickLower,
      tickUpper: tickUpper,
      amount0Desired: amount0Desired,
      amount1Desired: amount1Desired,
      amount0Min: amount0Min,
      amount1Min: amount1Min,
      recipient: recipient,
      deadline: deadline,
    }

    const signer = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum).getSigner(
      recipient
    )

    const nonfungible = new ethers.Contract(
      NONFUNGIBLE_POSITION_MANAGER_ADDRESS[chainId],
      Nonfungiblepositionmanager.abi,
      signer
    )

    const iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(Nonfungiblepositionmanager.abi)

    let calls = []

    calls.push(
      iface.encodeFunctionData("createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary", [
        token0,
        token1,
        fee,
        sqrtPrice,
      ])
    )

    calls.push(iface.encodeFunctionData("mint", [mintingParams]))

    if (isToken0Native || isToken1Native) {
      calls.push(iface.encodeFunctionData("refundETH"))
    }

    let initializeTx
    try {
      initializeTx = await nonfungible.multicall(calls, {
        value: nativeCurrencyValue,
      })
    } catch (rejectedError) {
      if (rejectedError.code === "UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT") {
        initializeTx = await nonfungible.multicall(calls, {
          value: nativeCurrencyValue,
          gasLimit: "10000000", // arbitrary value, should fine-tune for ShimmerEVM
        })
      }
    }
    initializeTx.wait()

    const result = {
      initializeSent: true,
      hash: initializeTx.hash,
    }

    return result
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error, "error for CreateInitializeMintToken")
    const result = {
      initializeSent: false,
      error: error,
    }
    return result
  }
}
```